# Is this a bug in the site, or in Internet Explorer?

Tags: bug, status-declined, html

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/do-you-ever-write-code-with-pen-and-paper-and-should-we-do-it-more-often/21307#21307

When I view my answer, it contains the following text

> ... I'll jot it down,
>  down,
>   instead ...

When I tried to edit it, I realized there is only one 'down'.    It seems that the word wrap algorithm at the new line is duplicating the word 'down'.  This happens in IE7 on Windows XP, regardless of how wide I have my window set.

Answer (score 2):

I recall seeing this before on IE7. Pretty sure it's a browser bug, and thus not something we can really fix.

(Plus IE7 is entering our "new IE6" designation, as we no longer support IE6.)

Comment: Your cutting off a lot of people though with IE 7 though: http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2010/11/windows-xp-falls-under-60-ie8-loses-share-for-the-first-time.ars http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2

Comment: You'd be surprised how much browser share differs from site to site. I highly doubt that many people browsing SO/SE sites will be using outdated browsers.